# ¿Cómo estimar correctamente el cambio porcentual de dos columnas considerando diferentes índices en las series con pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Supongamos que tengo la siguiente dataframe llamada `df_trading_pair`:

```
    Start Date           Open Price     High Price  Low Price   Close Price End Date
0   2022-07-20 08:00:00  0.19277        0.19324     0.19225     0.19324     2022-07-20 08:04:59.999
1   2022-07-20 08:05:00  0.19321        0.194       0.1932      0.19388     2022-07-20 08:09:59.999
2   2022-07-20 08:10:00  0.19387        0.195       0.19387     0.19489     2022-07-20 08:14:59.999
3   2022-07-20 08:15:00  0.19496        0.19628     0.19495     0.19626     2022-07-20 08:19:59.999
4   2022-07-20 08:20:00  0.19625        0.20406     0.19625     0.2035      2022-07-20 08:24:59.999
```

He estado intentando averiguar una forma simple para calcular el cambio porcentual de **los primeros 4** elementos en la columna `Open Price` vs **los últimos 4** elementos en la columna `Close Price`, de manera que logre obtener la siguiente salida en otra dataframe llamada `new_df`:

```
 Close Price vs Open Price % change
0                            0.0057
1                            0.0087
2                            0.0123
3                            0.0438
dtype: float64
```

Inicialmente, Yo pensé que la siguiente línea de código funcionaría perfectamente, dado que ambos arreglos tendrían 4 elementos y contendrían los valores exactos que necesito:

```
new_df["Close Price vs Open Price % change"] = (df_trading_pair["Close Price"][1:]-df_trading_pair["Open Price"][:-1])/df_trading_pair["Open Price"][:-1]
```

Sin embargo, después de ejecutar esa línea la consola me arrojó la siguiente salida:

```
 Close Price vs Open Price % change
0                               NaN
1                          0.003468
2                          0.005261
3                          0.006668
4                               NaN
dtype: float64
```

Lo cual no entiendo, también decidí probar esta otra línea de código distinta:

```
new_df["Close Price vs Open Price % Change"] = [(y-x)/x*100 for x in df_trading_pair["Open Price"][:-1] for y in df_trading_pair["Close Price"][1:]]
```

La cual también me hizo creer que funcionaría, pero esta desafortunadamente arrojó el siguiente error:

> ```
> ValueError: Length of values (16) does not match length of index (5)
> ```

Entonces, quisiera saber ¿qué he hecho mal, o qué otra solución podría servir mejor para obtener la salida que deseo?

Comment: Hola, buen día, la salida que espero obtener la menciono justo después de mostrar los de datos de la dataframe `df_trading_pair` al inicio del post, básicamente busco calcuar los cambios porcentuales de los primeros 4 datos de la columna `Open Price` con respecto a los últimos 4 datos de la columna `Close Price`, para guardar dichas estimaciones en otra dataframe llamada `new_df`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

La razón por la que no funciona es porque lo que haces en esta línea:

```
new_df["Close Price vs Open Price % change"] = (df_trading_pair["Close Price"][1:]-df_trading_pair["Open Price"][:-1])/df_trading_pair["Open Price"][:-1]
```

Es únicamente filtrar el `dataframe` por lo que los valores siguen ligados a los índices y al restarlos (O hacer cualquier otra operación) lo va a realizar mapeando índice por índice (0 con 0, 1 con 1, etc...).

La solución simple es únicamente agregar `.values` a cada filtro, para trabajar con los valores y no con el filtro, de la siguiente forma:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
new_df["Close Price vs Open Price % change"] = (df_trading_pair["Close Price"][1:].values - df_trading_pair["Open Price"][:-1].values)/df_trading_pair["Open Price"][:-1].values
```

Esto devuelve el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
    Close Price vs Open Price % change
0   0.005758
1   0.008695
2   0.012328
3   0.043804
```

Pero yo creo que aún así hay otra forma que te convendría más en caso de utilizar `dataframes` más extensos, esto es utilizando [`pandas.DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
new_df["Close Price vs Open Price % change"] = (df_trading_pair.iloc[-4:]['Close Price'].values - df_trading_pair.iloc[:4]['Open Price'].values) / df_trading_pair.iloc[:-1]['Open Price'].values
```

Utilizamos los `slices` `[-4:]` para los últimos 4 elementos y `[:4]` para los primeros cuatro elementos, y se les agregan sus respectivas columnas tal como se muestra en el ejemplo anterior.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Aprecio que hayas tomado el tiempo de explicar detalladamente las razones por las que no me funcionó, ahora sé un poquito más =).

Comment: No hay de que, recuerda que parte fundamental de trabajar con `dataframes` es que las "celdas" siempre están ligadas a los índices y las columnas, es por eso que trabajan eficientemente. Saludos!